# Uploading C program to the ARM core for execution through ethernet!

Tags: fpga, vhdl, arm, xilinx, arm9

I want to write a c code on my local PC and upload it to ARM core on Zed-board for execution. I know we can do it using JTAG, but for obvious reason I want to use Ethernet interface.

I will be glad to explain more if i am missing the right words to explain my problem.

Many Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you running any sort of operating system? I've never used that particular board but if running bare metal writing an ethernet bootloader might be quite involved. If running Linux you'd just use FTP or similiar to copy across the cross-compiled executable.

Comment: If you get something like U-boot on there (not unlikely as it appears the board supports Linux, and they are often used together), you should have that capability through it.

Comment: Dear Chris, Many thanks for your comments. I will glad if you could tell me a bit more on how to use U boot.

Answer (score 2):

You would need either

- an ethernet-to-jtag bridge (hardware and software): this keeps you current interface intact, including debugging. I have no idea whether this exists for your setup.

or

- an ethernet bootloader running on the chip + development environment settings that can work with a bootloader + a way to reset the chip (press the switch?) + a way to let the bootloader know that it has to bootload (instead of running the existing application)(switch? jumper?)

PS I don't know which 'obvious' reason you have for wanting to use ethernet instead of jtag.

Comment: Two obvious guesses would be speed and using only cheap/widely available commodity interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, and you mention two, so I still don't know which is the obvious reason (singluar) the TS hints at.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable ideas.The only obvious reason i thought about is Speed.The idea behind this is to design a pulse generator( with min. 100 channels).We already have a firmware running in which we transfer the data from host pc to fpga(virtex-5) using ethernet (less channels) and I see that ethernet act as bottle-neck while transferring the long sequences to fpga, so i want to generate sequences on fpga to get ride of this problem hence I find it more reasonable to develop a firmware with Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an application on top of OS, NFS/FTP/scp are some of the possible ways.

If you are running a full OS image, you could still use tftp with some boot-loader like uboot as chris stratton mentioned above. For example,

`Boot-loader --> tftp --> Target_image`

Resetting the target board is still a problem that should be solved outside the boot-loader/tftp control, though. One way is to have software reset the board by itself.

I tend to use NFS. I just mount the target directory as NFS share within the board (e.g. RasPi). Just copy the build to the target directory and SSH a command to RasPi.

As most others said before me, it would highly depend upon what you have to run.